# Flot chart To show different year's data in order on X axis

Tags: javascript, flot, graphic

I have a data array which consists of timestamp - value pairs.

Basically there are two sets of data; 2014 and 2015 values.

For;

**2014.12 : There are 4 values**

**2015.1 : There are 4 values.**

**2015.2 : There are 4 values.**

**2015.3 : There are 4 values.**

I want to show them in order, 2014 values first , and so on.

However I end up showing values without time order starting from 1 to 12 on x axis. 
Is there any way of setting the x axis in order based on my array data?

```
  Fiddle;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/shamaleyte/6gL1wzsL/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the time plugin & mode to show date/time & values pairs.

```
xaxis: {
    mode: 'time'
},
```

See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gL1wzsL/5/) and the [chapter in the documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data).